# SQL Developer returns query results on one computer but not on another

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I can run a query on views in SQL Developer 3.1.07 and it returns the results I expect. My co-worker, who is in Mexico using the same user, can connect to the same database, sees the same views, runs the same query and gets no results, even from a simple "select * from VIEWNAME" query. The column headers display, but no data. If he selects a view from the connections window and selects the DATA tab no data displays. This user does not have access to any tables on this specific database.

I'm not certain he is running the same version of Developer, but it's not far off. I have checked as many settings in SQL Developer that I think could be the issue, but see no significant difference in his settings from mine.

Connecting to another database allows him to access data in both tables and views

Any thoughts on what we're missing?

Comment: Connecting as the same user? Just to eliminate the obvious, since you didn't mention it. Different users with their own copies of the tables seems possible, so would need to be ruled out. Which makes them not the 'same' tables of course, but still...

Comment: Of course, thanks Alex, yes we are both accessing the database with the same user information.

Comment: Value of 'Sql Array Fetch Size' is 100. Column metadata does show. Running the query as a script returns "no rows selected". Actually they are views and not tables (neither of us have access to any tables in this particular database. I did connect to a different database from his machine and was able to get results from queries to both tables and views. Original question has been edited with this information

Comment: That's a stumper then. It doesn't seem to be a client setting, unless it's in the connection settings, if only one DB is affected. t guess the views could be using `sys_context` to filter as a kind of VPD, based on OS user or IP, but that sounds rather unlikely. I can't think of any reason the same Oracle user on the same DB would have different data visibility based on the client. Intriguing.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a few years late, but check if the underlying view doesn't filter on something that is based on localisation! I just had the issue and it turned out to be a statment like this that was causing issues:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sometable
WHERE language = userenv('LANG')
```

Comment: I was able to confirm this in my environment by changing my db explorer's language to something else before running the queries. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same which got resolved when I checked the 'skip NLS settings' box. My query was returning zero results earlier but when I ran the same query again, I could see the table rows.

Since your co-worker is in a different country, most probably the NLS settings (related to the language) are the culprit here.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the JDBC folder from your oracle home and copy it over to your c-workers machine. we had the same issue and replacing the JDBC folder worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, turned out that the update to the database from my sqldevelolper was not commited to the main database, that's why, I was getting results on my sqldeveloper for that query, but from aws it was returning empty results. When I chatted with DBA, he could find stale data. After I committed the data from my sqldeveloper, the db was actually updated.